# Libgdx: Character movement and animation

Tags: android, animation, input, libgdx, game-engine

Good day dear sirs. I have encountered a problem with the animation and controls of my character. My problem is whenever I tried to press the left and right arrow key my player moves up and down instead of going left and right. I did tried to debug my code by I still can't find out which part of the code is wrong. That's why I'm asking you guys to look up my code and could possibly tell which part of the code is wrong or needs improvement.

This is my code for my player:

```
public class DugmanPlayer {
    public enum state
    {
        standby,
        walking,
        digging,
        dying
    }

    public enum dir
    {
        left,
        right,
        up,
        down
    }

    public static float WIDTH;
    public static float HEIGHT;
    static float speedmax = 30f;
    static float damping = 0.9f;
    dir d = dir.up;

    public Vector2 position = new Vector2();
    public Vector2 speed = new Vector2();
    state st = state.walking;

    public float statetime = 0;

    public void UpdatePlayer(float deltatime)
    {
        if(deltatime==0)return;
        statetime += deltatime;
        //rightwalking
        if(Math.abs(speed.x) > speedmax) {
            speed.x = Math.signum(speed.x) * speedmax;
            if(d != dir.left)d = dir.right;
            st = state.walking;
        }

        if(Math.abs(speed.x) < 1) {
            speed.x = 0;
            if(st!=state.walking)st = state.standby;
            d=dir.right;
        }
        //upwalking
        if(Math.abs(speed.y) > speedmax) {
            speed.y = Math.signum(speed.y) * speedmax;
            if(d != dir.down)d = dir.up;
            st = state.walking;
        }

        if(Math.abs(speed.y) < 1) {
            speed.y = 0;
            if(st != state.walking)st = state.standby;
            d=dir.up;
        }

        if(Math.abs(-speed.x)>speedmax)
        {
            speed.x = Math.signum(-speed.x) * speedmax;
            if(d != dir.right)d = dir.left;
            st = state.walking;
        }
        if(Math.abs(-speed.x)<1)
        {
            speed.x = 0;
            if(st!=state.walking)st = state.standby;
            d=dir.up;
        }

        if(Math.abs(-speed.y)>speedmax){
            speed.y = Math.signum(-speed.y) * speedmax;
            if(d != dir.up)d = dir.down;
            st = state.walking;
        }
        if(Math.abs(-speed.y)<1)
        {
            speed.y = 0;
            if(st!=state.walking)st = state.standby;
            d=dir.down;
        }

        speed.scl(deltatime);

        position.add(speed);
        speed.scl(1/deltatime);

        // Apply damping to the velocity on the x-axis so we don't
        // walk infinitely once a key was pressed
        speed.x *= damping;
        speed.y *= damping;

        InputProcess();
    }

    TextureRegion left;
    TextureRegion right;
    TextureRegion up;
    TextureRegion down;
    TextureRegion standby;
    Animation Walkingleft;
    Animation WalkingRight;
    Animation WalkingUp;
    Animation WalkingDown;
    Animation stndbyleft,stndbyright,stndbyup,stndbydown;

    public void LoadPlayerTexture()
    {
        TextureAtlas dug = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("character/walking.pack"));
        left = dug.findRegion("faceleft");
        right = dug.findRegion("faceright");
        up = dug.findRegion("faceup");
        down = dug.findRegion("facedown");

        TextureRegion[] leftwalk = left.split(left.getRegionWidth()/3, left.getRegionHeight()/1)[0];
        TextureRegion[] rightwalk = right.split(right.getRegionWidth()/3, right.getRegionHeight()/1)[0];
        TextureRegion[] upwalk = up.split(up.getRegionWidth()/3, up.getRegionHeight()/1)[0];
        TextureRegion[] downwalk = down.split(down.getRegionWidth()/3, down.getRegionHeight()/1)[0];

        Walkingleft = new Animation(0.5f, leftwalk[0],leftwalk[1],leftwalk[2]);
        WalkingRight = new Animation(0.5f, rightwalk[0],rightwalk[1],rightwalk[2]);
        WalkingUp = new Animation(0.5f, upwalk[0],upwalk[1],upwalk[2]);
        WalkingDown = new Animation(0.5f, downwalk[0],downwalk[1],downwalk[2]);

        stndbyleft = new Animation(0, leftwalk[1]);
        stndbyright = new Animation(0, rightwalk[1]);
        stndbyup = new Animation(0, upwalk[1]);
        stndbydown = new Animation(0, downwalk[1]);

        DugmanPlayer.WIDTH = 1/16f * leftwalk[0].getRegionWidth();
        DugmanPlayer.HEIGHT = 1/16f * leftwalk[0].getRegionHeight();
    }

    public void DrawPlayer(float deltatime, OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer r)
    {
        Animation fm = null;
        boolean loop = true;

        switch (st) {
        case standby: if(speed.y == 0){
        fm = stndbyup;
        }
        else if(-speed.y == 0){
        fm = stndbydown;
        }else if (speed.x == 0) {
        fm = stndbyright;
        }else if (-speed.x == 0) {
        fm = stndbyleft;
        }
            break;
        case walking: if(speed.y>speedmax){
        fm = WalkingUp;
        }else if(-speed.y>speedmax){
        fm = WalkingDown;
        }else if (speed.x>speedmax) {
        fm = WalkingRight;
        }else if (-speed.x>speedmax) {
        fm = Walkingleft;
        }
        break;
        case digging:
            break;
        case dying:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


        SpriteBatch batch = r.getSpriteBatch();

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(fm.getKeyFrame(statetime, loop), position.x, position.y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        batch.end();
    }

    public void InputProcess()
    {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            if(st != state.standby)st = state.walking;
            speed.y += speedmax;
            d = dir.up;
        }
        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
            if(st!=state.standby)st = state.walking;
            speed.y = -speedmax;
            d = dir.down;
        }
        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
            if(st!=state.standby)st = state.walking;
            speed.y = -speedmax;
            d = dir.left;
        }
        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
            if(st!=state.standby)st = state.walking;
            speed.y += speedmax;
            d = dir.right;
        }
        else
        {
            st = state.standby;
            speed.x = 0;
            speed.y = 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

What I did with my character class is that it will contain all the inputs for my character, render the animation to specific states and direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
 else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {

            if(st!=state.standby)st = state.walking;
            speed.y = -speedmax;
            d = dir.left;

        }


        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {

            if(st!=state.standby)st = state.walking;
            speed.y += speedmax;
            d = dir.right;

        }
```

dont you think that u shuld use speed.x instead of speed.y in this code :)

Comment: Thanks! It did work. I'am able to move left and right now but my problem now is the animation. Does it have to do anything with my update method or draw method? What I wanted for my animation is that whenever I press and hold my down key my animation would be walkingdown and when I release the key the animation would be stndbydown.

Comment: so where are u stucking?? on pressing down button is down animation running but on releasing the button its not coming to standbydown?? or somthing else??? wot have u tried till now????

Comment: I tried changing the speed.y to speed.x, this made my player move left and right already. My animation is not responding with my keys, What it is suppose to do is whenever I press up and hold it the animation would be walkingup and once I release my up key the animation would be stndbyup. Well, what I tried before asking is improving my update method but it still didn't do any good. I can't seem to find whats wrong.